# PHP PNG 24 bit clean Transparency

Tags: php, png, transparency

I have been trying to get a PNG to upload with a clean, 24 bit alpha transparency. After doing a lot of research, I have managed to get it sort of working, however the transparency seems to be low quality 8 bit as you can see here in this screenshot:

http://cozomo.com/apple.png

Any help to achieve a clean PNG upload and resize with 24 bit smooth transparency would be much appreciated. My current code is below.

```
if($extension=="png")
    {
        $uploadedfile = $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'];
        $src = imagecreatefrompng($uploadedfile);
    }

        $dest_x = 1400; 
        $dest_y = 1200;

        if ($width > $dest_x or $height > $dest_y) { 

                if ($width >= $height) { 
                    $fullSize_x = $dest_x; 
                    $fullSize_y = $height*($fullSize_x/$width); 
                } else { 
                    $fullSize_x = $width*($fullSize_y/$height); 
                    $fullSize_y = $dest_y; 
                } 
        }

        $fullSize=imagecreatetruecolor($fullSize_x,$fullSize_y);

    //TEST
    $black = imagecolorallocate($fullSize, 0, 0, 0);
    imagecolortransparent($fullSize, $black);
    //TEST END

    // OUTPUT NEW IMAGES
    imagecopyresampled($fullSize,$src,0,0,0,0,$fullSize_x,$fullSize_y,$width,$height);

    imagepng($fullSize, "/user/photos/".$filename);

    imagedestroy($fullSize);


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8VBI.png
```

Comment: A 32bit PNG's alpha channel only has 8bit resolution anyways. 24bits for RGB and 8bits for alpha.

Comment: (Incidentally, if you want the image to display _here_, hit the link "edited 17 seconds ago" (or whatever it says now) and hit "rollback" on my edit.)

Comment: this cant work easily because you're telling GD to 'hide' 0,0,0 color but what about the 0,2,0 or 2,1,0 colors that are 'black' but not 0,0,0? pls provide the original image to test.

Comment: @vlzvl Im not 100% sure what you're saying here - but here is the original PNG image I used http://www.inkscapegallery.net/files/images/apple.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To save the full alpha channel you'll have to use [`imagesavealpha`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagesavealpha.php), put this before you save the png

```
imagealphablending($fullSize, false);
imagesavealpha($fullSize, true);
```

Comment: Thank you Musa. I actually tried that earlier, but I guess I had it in the wrong place. Works like a charm now :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the revised code thanks to Musa for anyone having the same issue

```
function processPNG($pngImage) {
        $black = imagecolorallocate($pngImage, 0, 0, 0);
        imagecolortransparent($pngImage, $black);
        imagealphablending($pngImage, false);
        imagesavealpha($pngImage, true);
    }    


   if($extension=="png")
{
    $uploadedfile = $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'];
    $src = imagecreatefrompng($uploadedfile);
}

    $dest_x = 1400; 
    $dest_y = 1200;

    if ($width > $dest_x or $height > $dest_y) { 

            if ($width >= $height) { 
                $fullSize_x = $dest_x; 
                $fullSize_y = $height*($fullSize_x/$width); 
            } else { 
                $fullSize_x = $width*($fullSize_y/$height); 
                $fullSize_y = $dest_y; 
            } 
    }

    $fullSize=imagecreatetruecolor($fullSize_x,$fullSize_y);
    if ($extension == "png") processPNG($fullSize);


// OUTPUT NEW IMAGES
imagecopyresampled($fullSize,$src,0,0,0,0,$fullSize_x,$fullSize_y,$width,$height);

imagepng($fullSize, "/user/photos/".$filename);

imagedestroy($fullSize);
```